# Parse output and create an array

Tags: python, arrays

I am stuck trying to parse the following into something I can perform some simple logic on. What would be a good way to go about it?

```
IP address          Client-ID/              Lease expiration        Type
                    Hardware address/
                    User name
10.10.10.10      0000.0000.0000.0000       Jan 29 2024 03:20 AM    Automatic
10.10.10.11      0000.0000.0000.0001       Jan 29 2024 03:21 AM    Automatic
10.10.10.12      0000.0000.0000.0002       Jan 29 2024 03:22 AM    Automatic
```

I am attempting to do the following where output is the above text:

```
bindings = []
for row in output.splitlines():
    bindings.append(
        {'IP': row.split()[0],
         'Client-ID/': row.split()[1],
         'Lease expiration': row.split()[2],
         'Type': row.split()[3]}
    )
print([binding.get('IP') + " " + binding.get('Client-ID') for binding in bindings])
```

I am trying to end up with a list that I can iterate through and display the results. However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
    'Lease expiration': row.split()[2],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You can tell `split` what separator to use; that might help.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have tried that and I get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You can split by 2 or 3 white spaces. Then .strip() the result :)

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question. Please read [ask]. You might want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be a good way to go about it?

"Good" is subjective, but your way almost did it.

This skips the first line, assuming you know it will be a header, but you could just as well skip the first three lines.

Then it splits each line by delimiter and strips each element only to keep what is left.

If what’s left is four elements long, it assigns element to a key and appends the dictionary.

```py
output = """\
IP address          Client-ID/              Lease expiration        Type
                    Hardware address/
                    User name
10.10.10.10      0000.0000.0000.0000       Jan 29 2024 03:20 AM    Automatic
10.10.10.11      0000.0000.0000.0001       Jan 29 2024 03:21 AM    Automatic
10.10.10.12      0000.0000.0000.0002       Jan 29 2024 03:22 AM    Automatic
"""

bindings = []
delimiter = ' ' * 2
for line in output.splitlines()[1:]:
    line = [i for i in map(str.strip, line.split(delimiter)) if i]
    if len(line) == 4:
        bindings.append({
            'IP': line[0],
            'Client-ID': line[1],
            'Lease expiration': line[2],
            'Type': line[3]})

print([f"{binding.get('IP')} {binding.get('Client-ID')}" for binding in bindings])
```

Output:

```
['10.10.10.10 0000.0000.0000.0000', '10.10.10.11 0000.0000.0000.0001', '10.10.10.12 0000.0000.0000.0002']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this issue as you can not use delimiters which are very fragile to write code in such a way to parse the output.

```
import re
output = """IP address          Client-ID/              Lease expiration        Type
                    Hardware address/
                    User name
10.10.10.10      0000.0000.0000.0000       Jan 29 2024 03:20 AM    Automatic
10.10.10.11      0000.0000.0000.0001       Jan 29 2024 03:21 AM    Automatic
10.10.10.12      0000.0000.0000.0002       Jan 29 2024 03:22 AM    Automatic"""

bindings = []


for row in output.splitlines():
    match = re.search(r"(^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))", row.split()[0])
    if match:
        data = re.search(r"^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\s+ (\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4})\s+ (\S+\s+["
                         r"0-9]{1,2}\s+[0-9]{4}\s+[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\s+\S+)\s+(\S+)$", row)
        if data:
            bindings.append(
                {'IP': data.groups()[0],
                'Client-ID/': data.groups()[1],
                'Lease expiration': data.groups()[2],
                'Type': data.groups()[3]
                }
            )
            print([str(binding.get('IP')) + " " + str(binding.get('Client-ID')) for binding in bindings])
print(bindings)
```

Output:

```
[{'IP': '10.10.10.10', 'Client-ID/': '0000.0000.0000.0000', 'Lease expiration': 'Jan 29 2024 03:20 AM', 'Type': 'Automatic'}, {'IP': '10.10.10.11', 'Client-ID/': '0000.0000.0000.0001', 'Lease expiration': 'Jan 29 2024 03:21 AM', 'Type': 'Automatic'}, {'IP': '10.10.10.12', 'Client-ID/': '0000.0000.0000.0002', 'Lease expiration': 'Jan 29 2024 03:22 AM', 'Type': 'Automatic'}]
```